# Access to the webpage was denied Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

template

```
<span style="float: left; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="/media/{{image.path}}">{{image.name|slice:":25"}}</a></span>
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/tmp/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
 (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'incident.views.media_serve_protected'),

def media_serve_protected(request, path):
    if path.startswith("{id}/".format(id=request.user.id)):
        return serve(request, path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

I am able to upload the images.The uploaded images are get saved in tmp folder.I can see the image name with image url,but for viewing if i click the image url i am getting the error `"Access to the webpage was denied You are not authorized to access the webpage at http://192.168.100.12/media/root/16/20130816235304-photo0015.jpg. You may need to sign in."`

Answer (score 2):

Your `media_serve_protected` function is returning a Forbidden response if the url does not start with `media/<id>`. But your url is in the form `media/root/<id>`.

Comment: I changed the url as below (r'^media/', 'incident.views.media_serve_protected'), it is returning 404,any help please.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry,I changed the url and tried,it is returning 404 page not found error page.